# terraform remote exec provisioner failed to connect to ec2 instance

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to install nginx in ec2 using terraform and stuck with red underlined at private_key line stating that **"Unknown token: 35:23 IDENT file"**.

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
        "sudo apt-get update -y",
        "sudo apt-get install nginx -y",
        "sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start"
    ]
    connection {
        type="ssh"
        user="ubuntu"
        private_key = file("./remoteexec.pem")
        host=self.public_ip
    }
```

And terraform failed to connect with ec2instance and ended up displaying error like this error:

```
timeout - last error: SSH authentication failed (ubuntu@52.87.214.77:22): ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

.

What could be the reason?

Anyhelp is greatly appreciated
[image]

Comment: It is hard to tell from what you have here, but, if I had to guess, perhaps the private key does not correspond to the public key you gave the instance? It may help to show us the `aws_instance` resource...

Comment: `resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami = "${var.image}"
  instance_type = "${var.inst_type}"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  #vpc_security_group_ids=["${default.aws_security_group.mysg.id}"]
  #security_groups= ["${aws_security_group.mysg.id}"]
  key_name = "exec.pem"
  tags = {
      Name = "Ubuntu"
      Task="Remote Exec Provisioner"
      Tool = "Terraform"
    }
  volume_tags = {
    Name = "myvol_myec2"
  }
  root_block_device {
   volume_size = 10
  } `

Comment: @siyopao .There is the aws_resource code.Now it is throwing error like this **Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidKeyPair.NotFound: The key pair 'exec.pem' does not exist
        status code: 400, request id: 1ce48783-a770-41fd-b7ec-b5882fdda38b

  on main.tf line 2, in resource "aws_instance" "ec2":
   2: resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
**

Comment: Do you have a key named "exec.pem" stored in aws (under ec2 --> key pairs)? And is it the corresponding public key of "remoteexec.pem"? If not, then what you have will not work. You can first try to upload your public key using `aws_key_pair` and then use the `key_name` output of that resource as input to `key_name` in `aws_instance`.

Comment: Can you check in your ec2 instance (/home/{User}/.ssh/authorised_key/) is there the public key which resemble the pem file you are providing.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what the error is but are you able to use the same key to connect from your terminal? In many instances a common problem is not having right read permissions for the key.